# Jquery Autocomplete remote datasource to multiple textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server

Is it possible to use [jQuery Autocomplete Remote Datasource](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) and display the results into multiple textbox instead of one as given in the jQuery page? If yes, how?

**EDIT**

As stated in the linked page on the view source (line 27)

```
"Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
```

can i display `ui.item.value` into one textbox and `ui.item.id` into another textbox ?

Comment: sure you can. if you look at the 'view source' on the page you linked to, you can see that you can work with the results in `select: function( event, ui ) { ... }`. just put your multiple textbox selectors inside.

Comment: @Sean its not the textbox selectors, its the textbox where the results were displayed. I managed to fetch the whole row of the data searched by the user. What i want now is display the whole row (multiple columns) into multiple textboxes.

Comment: well, can you provide some sample code, and some desired results? right now your question is really broad.

Comment: just select the textboxes that you want and give them the desired value -> `select: function( event, ui ) { $('#textbox1').val(ui.item.value); $('#textbox2').val(ui.item.id); }`

Comment: @Sean it works! Thanks :) can you post as answers? so i can accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the autocomplete `select:` you can display your results how ever you would like, ie.

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#textbox1').val(ui.item.value); 
        $('#textbox2').val(ui.item.id);
},
```